# Pythone ValueError with Tuple being correct length

Tags: python, tuples

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Data Munger/new_munger.py", line 49, in <module>
    for a, b in temp_tuple:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

from the following code:

```
for key in d:
    for temp in d[key]:
        temp_tuple = (temp[0], [temp[i] for i in range(1, len(temp))])
        print(len(temp_tuple))
        e = defaultdict(list)
        for a, b in temp_tuple:
            e.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
```

The `print(len(temp_tuple))` line is spitting out 2 in the console. I can't figure out why this error is being raised.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is already iterating over `temp_tuple`. In the first instance, you're trying to unpack `temp[0]` to `a` and `b`. Possibly what you meant to do is:

```
a, b = temp_tuple
e.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue. I think I've been staring at it too long. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

While the temp_tuple may be of length 2, your for wants each ITEM in temp_tuple to be 2 items (i.e. a tuple of length 2 tuples).